# iOS and Android Installation (direct testing)

Tags: android, ios

Is is possible to directly deploy apps on ios or android devices just for testing?

**My Background:**

I am currently developing iOS and Android apps but using only emulators.

Maybe you can consider me as an intermediate mobile developer but newbie in direct installation of application created.

**Also,** I'm afraid my iPhone or my android devices get destroyed if I will try some of the blogs tutorials found on the net.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try your application on actual mobile devices on both platforms.

With Android is pretty straightforward: just plugin your device to your computer's USB port. If you happen to have proper drivers for it, whenever you run your application from Eclipse IDE, you will be asked if you want to run your application directly on the device. Make sure you enable **debugging** on your device.

With iOS, it's also fairly easy. Just plug your iPhone/iPad/iPodTouch to your Mac, launch XCode and select **device** before pressing run. You might need to create a provisioning profile for it (you will need a Apple iOS Developer Account for this).

I don't think you will ruin any device just by following (and installing) tutorials from the net.

Answer (score 1):

For Android: Yes, you can run the apps directly from Eclipse or Netbeans on your device, works exactly as with the emulator. To make real apps you have to test them on real devices!
You wont destroy your device. Read the Android SDK "getting started" stuff. 
Can't really say about iOS though.

Answer (score 1):

You can always buy a second hand cheap phone and use it.
I started developing apps in the Android emulator and I was surprised about the big difference between the emulator en a real device, which really made it worth to buy one of these terminals.